# How to detect 'the URL for download link' of a package which in npmjs.org or its mirror site?

Tags: git, github, npm

I want to know a package's download direct link, it can be a package's zipball link, or a file's direct link, it can come from npmjs.com, or a mirror site, such as https://npm.taobao.org and so on.

I just want to know the combination rules of the download direct link.

What the rules are?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I find the solution.

http://registry.npmjs.org/vue
http://registry.npm.taobao.org/vue

Search 'tarball'.